# how i can dynamically parse my JSON data by making a getter setter class and a POJO class?

Tags: android, json, pojo

This is my JSON data.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-05-09 11:29:28:104",
  "token": null,
  "status": 0,
  "message": null,
  "result": {
    "emailId": "test@interrait.com",
    "gender": "m",
    "dob": "1994-04-01 05:30:00:0",
    "anniversary": "2017-08-12 05:30:00:0",
    "mobileno": null,
    "isAdmin": false,
    "isVerified": false,
    "lastLogin": "2017-05-09 11:29:26:258",
    "createdDate": "2017-05-09 11:29:26:258",
    "token": null,
    "tokenValidTime": null,
    "name": "test",
    "id": 27
  }
}
```

And this is my POJO class

```
public class SignUp {

  @SerializedName("message")
  private Object mMessage;
  @SerializedName("result")
  private Result mResult;
  @SerializedName("status")
  private Long mStatus;
  @SerializedName("timestamp")
  private String mTimestamp;
  @SerializedName("token")
  private Object mToken;

  public Object getMessage() {
    return mMessage;
  }

  public void setMessage(Object message) {
    mMessage = message;
  }

  public Result getResult() {
    return mResult;
  }

  public void setResult(Result result) {
    mResult = result;
  }

  public Long getStatus() {
    return mStatus;
  }

  public void setStatus(Long status) {
    mStatus = status;
  }

  public String getTimestamp() {
    return mTimestamp;
  }

  public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    mTimestamp = timestamp;
  }

  public Object getToken() {
    return mToken;
  }

  public void setToken(Object token) {
    mToken = token;
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use GSon library:

```
SignUp si = new Gson().fromJson("JSON_STRING", SignUp.class);
```

Comment: what is JSON_STRING? what does it refer to? I want to parse my json data dynamically using POJO class and then display it in a textview

Comment: Your JSON data.